# How can I set a true/false variable with if?

Tags: python, windows

It's kinda hard to explain, but I will try my best.

I have this part on my code

```
def hideConsole():
    hideConsole = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
    win32gui.ShowWindow(hideConsole, 0)
```

which hides the console, and I have this part to enable it

```
def onKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.KeyID == 192 and event.Alt == 32:
        hideConsole()
    return True
```

how can I make a "system" where when I press the key combination one time, the console hides, and the next time, the console will show up? (change the hideConsole, 1 value)

Comment: The answers below are good, but also keep in mind that if other things can show/hide the console, you'll need to choose the best solution that works with other players of the program.

Comment: While it shouldn't cause a problem here, it's a bad idea stylistically to have a local variable with the same name as the containing function. It's not grammatical, after all: `hideConsole` suggests an action, and the variable does not contain an action, but a thing. `consoleToHide` might be a better variable name. *Not that you really need one*; it's perfectly fine to just write `win32gui.ShowWindow(win32console.GetConsoleWindow(), 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function attribute that you switch between true and false on each call:

```
def toggleConsole():
    toggleConsole.show = not getattr(toggleConsole, "show", True)
    console = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
    win32gui.ShowWindow(console, int(toggleConsole.show))
```

Here is a quick example of how this works:

```
>>> def test():
...     test.show = not getattr(test, "show", True)
...     print int(test.show)
... 
>>> test()
0
>>> test()
1
>>> test()
0
```

Comment: There is a sense in which this is Perl-ish compared to making a proper class, but I like it. Simple is better than complex.

Comment: Beautiful, never thought of this before.

Answer (score 1):

With a boolean variable, something like this:

```
class Console(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_hidden = False
        self.handle    = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()

    def toggle(self):
        win32gui.ShowWindow(self.handle, 1 if self.is_hidden else 0)
        self.is_hidden = not self.is_hidden
```

Comment: Fly, meet sledgehammer.  I like it.

Comment: @Gringo Suave: Object Orientation is good for exactly two things: encapsulating state and communication through (polymorphic) messages, ASKA methods. OO can be implemented through classes or prototypes, or, if you're poor, through closures, or, if you're very poor, through function pointers. Doesn't matter. In Python you'd use a class. Cat's solution is the obvious and right way to do it, since it encapsulates state and changes it only through method calls.

Comment: Yes its elegant, I like it, didn't say I didn't.  Just feels heavy for 2 or 3 lines of code.

Comment: I think `int(self.is_hidden)` conveys the meaning more directly; the parameter to the underlying API call is an integer that is being used in a boolean sense, simply because of the lack of a true boolean type in C (at least originally).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: `ShowWindow` can take several integral constants as the second argument, not just 0 and 1. Ideally, it should be `SW_SHOWNORMAL` and `SW_HIDE` instead of integers, but I don't remember if/where pywin32 exposes those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state variable `hideValue` with initial value 0, and for each keyboard event do:

```
hideValue = 1 - hideValue
```

This will toggle `hideValue` between 0 and 1.

Then you can call `win32gui.ShowWindow(hideConsole, hideValue)`.

Comment: Tricks like this should be accompanied with an explaining comment though. Using a boolean flag and `not` takes a line more, but is simpler.

Comment: It's better (more readable) to use Boolean values. Like this: `hidevalue = False`, and then `hidevalue = not hidevalue`

Comment: @delnan, @Denilson I've just noticed that it would be much more readable to use the name `showValue` instead of `hideValue`. Regarding toggling Boolean values or integers, I thought it was pretty much on the same level, but maybe you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain state somehow:

```
hidden = False

def toggleConsoleVisibility():
    global hidden

    hideConsole = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
    win32gui.ShowWindow(hideConsole, 1 if hidden else 0)
    hidden = not hidden

def onKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.KeyID == 192 and event.Alt == 32:
        toggleConsoleVisibility()
    return True
```

If possible, write this as part of a class.  Then you can keep the `hidden` variable encapsulated by the class instead of floating around in your global namespace.

Comment: Python's ternary `if` is written as `<true> if <expr> else <false>`, not with `?:`.

Comment: Ah yes, I work with many languages and get them mixed together. :( Thanks for the correction.

Comment: There are several syntax problems, but I like this approach.

Comment: @cdhowie: What Cat Plus Plus said. Also, unless `hidden` is declared global in `toggleConsoleVisibility()` your code won't run, but raise an `UnboundLocalError`. Using `global` is usually a sign of bad design, though.

Comment: @pillmuncher: Indeed, thanks for the tip regarding `global`.  I usually design classes instead of using global variables, so I'm not very familiar with `global`.  Also, I'm pretty sure it needs to go in `toggleConsoleVisibility`, not `onKeyboardEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

```
con_visible = True

def setVisibility(visible):
    global con_visible
    hideConsole = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
    win32gui.ShowWindow(hideConsole, int(visible))
    con_visible = bool(visible)

def onKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.KeyID == 192 and event.Alt == 32:
        if con_visible:
            setVisibility(False)
        else:
            setVisibility(True)
    return True
```

If the console holds its visibility state internally you could preferably use that instead of a global variable.